# catia vba Drafting sheet format frame display

Tags: vba, catia

I have a little macro that adds a new sheet to a drawing intended for creating a .dxf file for the laser cut-out of sheet-metal parts.

```
Sub CATMain()

Dim drawingDocument1 As DrawingDocument
Set drawingDocument1 = CATIA.ActiveDocument

Dim drawingSheets1 As DrawingSheets
Set drawingSheets1 = drawingDocument1.Sheets

Dim drawingSheet1 As DrawingSheet
Set drawingSheet1 = drawingSheets1.Add("Laser")

drawingSheet1.PaperSize = catPaperA0

drawingSheet1.[Scale] = 1#

drawingSheet1.Orientation = catPaperLandscape

CATIA.StartCommand "Unfolded View"

End Sub
```

I'd like to make an addition to this macro where it removes the border of the sheet format.
The manual method of doing this is shown in the following screenshot:

[image]

So I either need to find a VBA command to untick that box, or a command to use Sheet Style "NoBorderTest" (as seen in the screenshot).
I couldn't find a way to do either, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm trying to accomplish exactly the same thing you are, I'm making drawings that contain a view scaled 1:1 that can be exported as a DXF for 3 axis machining. The format is very annoying, it makes it difficult to see the part profile if its size is similar to the paper dimensions. The drawing format "shadow" hides the geometry.

The work around that I came up with was to set the paper height and paper width to very small numbers, 0.0000001 seemed to work fine. The paper height and paper width properties are exposed APIs that you can work with:

```
Dim DXFRoot As DrawingRoot = DXFRepRef.GetItem("CATDrawingAccess")
Dim DXFSheets As DrawingSheets = DXFRoot.Sheets
Dim DXFSheet As DrawingSheet = DXFSheets.ActiveSheet
DXFSheet.PaperSize = CatPaperSize.catPaperUser
DXFSheet.Scale = 1
DXFSheet.SetPaperHeight(0.0000001)
DXFSheet.SetPaperWidth(0.0000001)
```